# cmake link error - order dependency or something else?

Tags: cmake, g++

I'm trying to build [Sigil](https://github.com/user-none/Sigil) on Ubuntu 14.04.  It compiles but won't link.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382075/undefined-python-references-in-g) (the error there looks very much like what I'm seeing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204820/cmake-and-order-dependent-linking-of-shared-libraries).  I was sure I'd found the culprit, but when I looked in the build files, the Python libraries were already last in the link order:

```
kevin@aphrodite:~/src/Sigil$ grep -r 'target_link_libraries' .
./src/CMakeLists.txt~:target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_MAIN} ${HUNSPELL_LIBRARIES} ${PCRE_LIBRARIES} gumbo ${MINIZIP_LIBRARIES} ${BOOST_LIBS} ${XERCES_LIBRARIES} ${XERCESEXTENSIONS_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} )
./src/CMakeLists.txt:target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_MAIN} ${HUNSPELL_LIBRARIES} ${PCRE_LIBRARIES} gumbo ${MINIZIP_LIBRARIES} ${BOOST_LIBS} ${XERCES_LIBRARIES} ${XERCESEXTENSIONS_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} )
./3rdparty/minizip/CMakeLists.txt:target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} )
./cmake_extras/FindPythonLibs.cmake:#    target_link_libraries(${_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

I'm not very familiar with cmake, so I'm stumped.  The only other thing I can think of is that I have two different versions of Python installed (2.7 and 3.4) because a bunch of core Ubuntu packages require 2.x and Sigil requires 3.x.  If that's the problem, I don't know what to do about it.

Here's the build command, which succeeds:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/bin/python3.4 -DFORCE_BUNDLED_COPIES=1 /home/kevin/src/Sigil
```

And here's the link command, which fails.  Are there any smoking guns here?

```
kevin@aphrodite:~/src/Sigil$ make linuxbinpkg
[  1%] Automatic moc for target sigil
[  1%] Built target sigil_automoc
[  5%] Built target gumbo
[ 10%] Built target zlib
[ 13%] Built target hunspell
[ 14%] Built target minizip
[ 21%] Built target pcre
Linking CXX executable ../bin/sigil
/usr/bin/ld: error in /usr/bin/python3.4(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::instance()':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `PyEval_InitThreads'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `PyEval_SaveThread'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::EmbeddedPython()':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `PyEval_InitThreads'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `PyEval_SaveThread'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::~EmbeddedPython()':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x27c): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x281): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2aa): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2af): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2dd): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x306): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::addToPythonSysPath(QString const&)':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x32a): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x339): undefined reference to `PySys_GetObject'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x35c): undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromString'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to `PyList_Append'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x3b6): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::QVariantToPyObject(QVariant&)':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0xd97): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0xdc9): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0xdeb): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0xe0e): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0xe31): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o:EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0xe57): more undefined references to `Py_BuildValue' follow
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::QVariantToPyObject(QVariant&)':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0xe82): undefined reference to `PyList_New'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0xeff): undefined reference to `PyList_SetItem'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x103d): undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromKindAndData'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x10a4): undefined reference to `PyList_New'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x114e): undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromKindAndData'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x115c): undefined reference to `PyList_SetItem'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x124b): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x1299): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::PyObjectToQVariant(_object*, bool)':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x179a): undefined reference to `PyFloat_Type'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x17a8): undefined reference to `PyType_IsSubtype'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x180a): undefined reference to `PyUnicode_AsUTF8'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x1944): undefined reference to `PyFloat_AsDouble'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x19e4): undefined reference to `PyLong_AsLongLong'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x1bec): undefined reference to `PyBytes_AsString'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x1dd4): undefined reference to `_PyUnicode_Ready'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x1e03): undefined reference to `PyTuple_Size'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x1e2f): undefined reference to `PyTuple_GetItem'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x1f8b): undefined reference to `PyList_Size'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x1fb7): undefined reference to `PyList_GetItem'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::getPythonErrorTraceback(bool)':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x25e0): undefined reference to `PyErr_Fetch'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x25f3): undefined reference to `PyErr_NormalizeException'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2604): undefined reference to `PyImport_ImportModule'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x263c): undefined reference to `PyObject_CallMethod'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2793): undefined reference to `PyErr_Clear'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::runInPython(QString const&, QString const&, QList<QVariant> const&, int*, QString&, bool)':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2b52): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2bbc): undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromString'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2bee): undefined reference to `PyImport_Import'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2c1b): undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2c54): undefined reference to `PyCallable_Check'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2c71): undefined reference to `PyErr_Occurred'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2d37): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2e9f): undefined reference to `PyTuple_New'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x2f35): undefined reference to `PyTuple_SetItem'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x3005): undefined reference to `PyObject_CallObject'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::callPyObjMethod(PyObjectPtr&, QString const&, QList<QVariant> const&, int*, QString&, bool)':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x318d): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x31f4): undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x3226): undefined reference to `PyCallable_Check'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x3243): undefined reference to `PyErr_Occurred'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x32cd): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x33b9): undefined reference to `PyTuple_New'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x3437): undefined reference to `PyTuple_SetItem'
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x34f6): undefined reference to `PyObject_CallObject'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o: In function `EmbeddedPython::~EmbeddedPython()':
EmbeddedPython.cpp:(.text+0x30c): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PyObjectPtr.cpp.o: In function `PyObjectPtr::~PyObjectPtr()':
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PyObjectPtr.cpp.o: In function `PyObjectPtr::setNewRef(_object*)':
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PyObjectPtr.cpp.o: In function `PyObjectPtr::fromVariant(QVariant const&)':
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x1df): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PyObjectPtr.cpp.o: In function `PyObjectPtr::setObject(_object*)':
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x42a): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x444): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PyObjectPtr.cpp.o: In function `PyObjectPtr::~PyObjectPtr()':
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PyObjectPtr.cpp.o: In function `QtMetaTypePrivate::QMetaTypeFunctionHelper<PyObjectPtr, true>::Destruct(void*)':
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text._ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE8DestructEPv[_ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE8DestructEPv]+0xf): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text._ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE8DestructEPv[_ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE8DestructEPv]+0x2d): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text._ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE8DestructEPv[_ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE8DestructEPv]+0x4f): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PyObjectPtr.cpp.o: In function `QtMetaTypePrivate::QMetaTypeFunctionHelper<PyObjectPtr, true>::Delete(void*)':
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text._ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE6DeleteEPv[_ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE6DeleteEPv]+0x14): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Ensure'
PyObjectPtr.cpp:(.text._ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE6DeleteEPv[_ZN17QtMetaTypePrivate23QMetaTypeFunctionHelperI11PyObjectPtrLb1EE6DeleteEPv]+0x2d): undefined reference to `PyGILState_Release'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [bin/sigil] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/linuxbinpkg.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [linuxbinpkg] Error 2
```

Here's the verbose output from the part that fails:

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/sigil
cd /home/kevin/src/Sigil/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/sigil_constants.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/TabBar.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/TabManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/FlowTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/ContentTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/TextTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/CSSTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/AVTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/ImageTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/MiscTextTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/SVGTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/OPFTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/NCXTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/WellFormedCheckComponent.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Tabs/XMLTab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/SourceUpdates/PerformHTMLUpdates.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/SourceUpdates/PerformOPFUpdates.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/SourceUpdates/PerformNCXUpdates.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/SourceUpdates/PerformCSSUpdates.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/SourceUpdates/AnchorUpdates.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/SourceUpdates/LinkUpdates.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/SourceUpdates/WordUpdates.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/SourceUpdates/UniversalUpdates.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/BookManipulation/Book.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/BookManipulation/BookReports.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/BookManipulation/Index.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/BookManipulation/CleanSource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/BookManipulation/FolderKeeper.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/BookManipulation/Headings.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/BookManipulation/Metadata.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/BookManipulation/XhtmlDoc.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/BookManipulation/GuideSemantics.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/Resource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/TextResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/HTMLResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/CSSResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/ImageResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/AudioResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/VideoResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/MiscTextResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/SVGResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/FontResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/OPFParser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/OPFResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/NCXResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ResourceObjects/XMLResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/About.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/AddMetadata.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ClipboardHistorySelector.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/DeleteFiles.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/DeleteStyles.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/EditTOC.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/OpenWithName.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/SelectCharacter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/SelectHyperlink.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/SelectId.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/SelectIndexTitle.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/SelectFiles.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/MetaEditor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/MetaEditorItemDelegate.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/HeadingSelector.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/PluginRunner.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/Preferences.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/PreferenceWidgets/AppearanceWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/PreferenceWidgets/CleanSourceWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/PreferenceWidgets/KeyboardShortcutsWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/PreferenceWidgets/LanguageWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/PreferenceWidgets/SpellCheckWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/PreferenceWidgets/PreserveEntitiesWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/PreferenceWidgets/PluginWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/RenameTemplate.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/Reports.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ReportsWidgets/AllFilesWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ReportsWidgets/HTMLFilesWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ReportsWidgets/LinksWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ReportsWidgets/ImageFilesWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ReportsWidgets/CSSFilesWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ReportsWidgets/ClassesInHTMLFilesWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ReportsWidgets/StylesInCSSFilesWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ReportsWidgets/CharactersInHTMLFilesWidget.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/LinkStylesheets.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/SearchEditor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ClipEditor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/IndexEditor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/SpellcheckEditor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Dialogs/ViewImage.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Exporters/ExportEPUB.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Exporters/ExporterFactory.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Exporters/NCXWriter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Exporters/XMLWriter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Exporters/EncryptionXmlWriter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Importers/ImportEPUB.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Importers/Importer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Importers/ImporterFactory.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Importers/ImportHTML.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Importers/ImportTXT.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/AppEventFilter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/UpdateChecker.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/Utility.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/FindReplaceQLineEdit.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/FilenameDelegate.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/XHTMLHighlighter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/CSSHighlighter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/CSSInfo.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/HTMLEncodingResolver.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/HTMLSpellCheck.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/HTMLPrettyPrint.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PasteTargetComboBox.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/Plugin.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PluginDB.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/QCodePage437Codec.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/RasterizeImageResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/SearchOperations.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/Language.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/UILanguage.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/SettingsStore.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/SpellCheck.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/KeyboardShortcut.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/KeyboardShortcutManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/XhtmlEntitiesDtd.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/Ncx20051Dtd.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/FontObfuscation.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/TempFolder.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/OpenExternally.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/TOCHTMLWriter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/ValidationResult.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/XMLEntities.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/PyObjectPtr.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/EmbeddedPython.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/Misc/GumboInterface.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MiscEditors/ClipEditorModel.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MiscEditors/ClipEditorTreeView.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MiscEditors/IndexEditorModel.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MiscEditors/IndexEditorTreeView.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MiscEditors/IndexEntries.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MiscEditors/IndexHTMLWriter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MiscEditors/SearchEditorTreeView.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MiscEditors/SearchEditorModel.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/pcre/SPCRE.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/pcre/PCRECache.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/pcre/PCREReplaceTextBuilder.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ViewEditors/BookViewEditor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ViewEditors/BookViewPreview.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ViewEditors/CodeViewEditor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ViewEditors/LineNumberArea.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ViewEditors/Searchable.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/ViewEditors/ViewWebPage.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/MainApplication.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/MainWindow.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/FindReplace.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/BookBrowser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/ClipsWindow.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/PreviewWindow.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/TableOfContents.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/OPFModel.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/OPFModelItem.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/NCXModel.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/MainUI/ValidationResultsView.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/qrc_main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/qrc_About.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/qrc_javascript.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/qrc_icon.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sigil.dir/sigil_automoc.cpp.o  -o ../bin/sigil -rdynamic ../lib/libhunspell.a ../lib/libpcre.a ../lib/libgumbo.a ../lib/libminizip.a /usr/bin/python3.4 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Xml.so.5.4.1 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5.4.1 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.4.1 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Svg.so.5.4.1 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5.4.1 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5.4.1 ../lib/libzlib.a /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.4.1 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5.4.1 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.4.1 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.4.1 /home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.4.1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/kevin/local/qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib
```

Comment: Try with `make VERBOSE=1` so that we can see the link command

Comment: It's pretty strange: after -o `../bin/sigil`there's a long list (among the elements there is a  `/usr/bin/python3.4`), but no -l option (link a library) or -L (linking directory). FYI, linking directories can be specified with the cmake command `link_directories`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antonio's suggestion to put in a call to `message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES = ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")` led me to /facepalm.

In my `cmake` command, I had put `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/bin/python3.4`.  That is an executable, not a library.  I'm not sure about the exact sequence of events that led me to put that in there, but I think it went like this:

- Tried to build with only Python 2.7 installed; `cmake` failed because it couldn't find a suitable version of Python.
- Installed Python 3.4.  If I tried to build again at this point, maybe it failed because `cmake` doesn't really have a "clean" option, so perhaps it was stuck on Python 2.7.
- Put in that bogus library path.

So then `cmake` succeeds, apparently happy with the bogus path which it doesn't actually use for anything, just writes in the Makefile.

After starting over with a clean project tree, I saw this line which I don't think I ever saw before:

```
Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so (found suitable version "3.4", minimum required is "3.4")
```

And now `make` works!

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, try to manually input the following command line

> [OMITTED, SEE EDIT HISTORY IF INTERESTED]

Basically I have only replaced Python3.4 with Python2.7; please double check the name of the library in /usr/bin

---

I see now you have a solution, the root problem is that in the CMakeLists.txt, this line

```
find_package (PythonLibs 3.4)
```

Should be:

```
find_package (PythonLibs 3.4 REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Same error.  `ls /usr/bin/python*` shows `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.4-config /usr/bin/python3.4m-config /usr/bin/python3m /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python3-config /usr/bin/python3m-config`.  All except `/usr/bin/python2.7`, `/usr/bin/python3.4`, and `/usr/bin/python3.4m` are symlinks.

Comment: In CMakeLists.txt, add `message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES = ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})`: you'll see to which python library (in theory) is trying to link. I still do not understand why you have no `-l` statements in the generated make command. Getting `-lpython2.7` in the command line [should solve the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13952106/2436175).

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede The message should be printed after `find_package (PythonLibs 3.4)`.  Probably also `-lpython3.4` would solve the problem.

Comment: Your suggestion led me to the solution.

Comment: Are you saying that would have overridden my stupid mistake, or prevented the behavior that led me to make it?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede When a project use `find_package` there are two options in case it doesn't find the package: either  it disables some features but than builds regularly all the rest, or it generates an error at cmake time. It can never be that it generates a project that doesn't build or that fails in linking. So, yes, it would have prevented your mistake, and forced you to work at your python installation until it was fixed. One note: CMake allows to clean, namely clearing its cache. I don't know the command line, but it's something you can easily access from one of the cmake-gui menus.